# gorm.io/gorm library can not work with graphQL

Tags: go, graphql, go-gorm

I am try to using **`github.com/jinzhu/gorm`** library with graphQL, when I use

```sh
 go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen init
 gqlgen generate
```

generate a graphQL project. And I code my logical to save data to MySQL innodb engine tables. Everything is fine execept that is db.AutoMigrate won't create foreign key constraint.

So. I change library to **'grom.io/gorm'**, the foreign key is created at db.AutoMigrate function called, but when I post data to the http server, there lot's of error message pop up.

The following is standard output of error message:

```sh
shell$ go run server.go
2020/12/21 10:19:45 connect to http://localhost:8080/ for GraphQL playground
not implemented

goroutine 34 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack(0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x9f
runtime/debug.PrintStack()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:16 +0x25
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.DefaultRecover(0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cd1a0, 0x8fedc0, 0xc000390320, 0x0, 0xa24420)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/recovery.go:16 +0xaa
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.(*OperationContext).Recover(0xc0004a0f00, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cd1a0, 0x8fedc0, 0xc000390320, 0x1e, 0x99ac79)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/context_operation.go:110 +0x56
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext)._Item_id.func1(0xc000390050, 0xc000390310, 0xc0000c8e88)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:418 +0x79
panic(0x8fedc0, 0xc000390320)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:969 +0x1b9
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph.(*itemResolver).ID(0xc000186290, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cd1a0, 0xc00027a480, 0xc00019ef60, 0xc0001cd1a0, 0xc00004b400)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/schema.resolvers.go:17 +0x68
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext)._Item_id.func2(0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cd1a0, 0x20, 0x945e40, 0xa2d501, 0xc00019ef60)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:433 +0x99
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/executor.processExtensions.func3(0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cd1a0, 0xc00019ef60, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cd1a0, 0x40f1b0, 0xc00019ef40)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/executor/extensions.go:62 +0x3a
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext)._Item_id(0xc000390050, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cd0e0, 0xc00048fe00, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc00027a480, 0x0, 0x0)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:431 +0x1f8
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext)._Item.func1(0x0, 0x0)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:2113 +0xc5
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.(*FieldSet).Dispatch(0xc000078460)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/fieldset.go:34 +0x1dd
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext)._Item(0xc000390050, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cd0e0, 0xc00006c5c0, 0x4, 0x4, 0xc00027a480, 0x68, 0x961740)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:2138 +0x406
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext).marshalNItem2ᚖgithubᚗcomᚋyangwawa0323ᚋgoᚑordersᚑgraphqlᚑapiᚋgraphᚋmodelᚐItem(0xc000390050, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cd0e0, 0xc00006c5c0, 0x4, 0x4, 0xc00027a480, 0x0, 0xc0000c9210)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:2615 +0x157
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext).marshalNItem2ᚕᚖgithubᚗcomᚋyangwawa0323ᚋgoᚑordersᚑgraphqlᚑapiᚋgraphᚋmodelᚐItemᚄ.func1(0x0)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:2595 +0xfd
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext).marshalNItem2ᚕᚖgithubᚗcomᚋyangwawa0323ᚋgoᚑordersᚑgraphqlᚑapiᚋgraphᚋmodelᚐItemᚄ(0xc000390050, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cd0b0, 0xc00006c5c0, 0x4, 0x4, 0xc000186258, 0x1, 0x1, 0x3, ...)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:2598 +0x27c
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext)._Order_items(0xc000390050, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc930, 0xc00048fd80, 0xc00006c5c0, 0x4, 0x4, 0xc00027a3f0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:818 +0x30b
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext)._Order(0xc000390050, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc930, 0xc0001cc8d0, 0x3, 0x3, 0xc00027a3f0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:2222 +0x5f3
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext).marshalNOrder2ᚖgithubᚗcomᚋyangwawa0323ᚋgoᚑordersᚑgraphqlᚑapiᚋgraphᚋmodelᚐOrder(0xc000390050, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc930, 0xc0001cc8d0, 0x3, 0x3, 0xc00027a3f0, 0xc0001cc960, 0xc0000c9610)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:2692 +0x157
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext)._Mutation_createOrder(0xc000390050, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc900, 0xc00048fc00, 0xc0001cc8d0, 0x3, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:594 +0x366
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext)._Mutation(0xc000390050, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc900, 0xc0004a9aa0, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc0001cc8a0, 0x30)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:2161 +0x67d
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executableSchema).Exec.func2(0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc8a0, 0x10)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:232 +0x7b
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/executor.(*Executor).DispatchOperation.func1.1.1(0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc8a0, 0xc000390060)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/executor/executor.go:105 +0x43
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/executor.processExtensions.func2(0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc8a0, 0xc000390060, 0xa19730)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/executor/extensions.go:59 +0x3a
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/executor.(*Executor).DispatchOperation.func1.1(0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc840, 0xc0001cc810)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/executor/executor.go:104 +0x12c
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/handler/transport.POST.Do(0xa2c1e0, 0xc0001e22a0, 0xc0004a0e00, 0xa2bda0, 0xc0001963f0)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/handler/transport/http_post.go:53 +0x3a8
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/handler.(*Server).ServeHTTP(0xc0001da1c0, 0xa2c1e0, 0xc0001e22a0, 0xc0004a0e00)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/handler/server.go:115 +0x21b
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xcd53e0, 0xa2c1e0, 0xc0001e22a0, 0xc0004a0d00)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2417 +0x1ad
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0001e2000, 0xa2c1e0, 0xc0001e22a0, 0xc0004a0d00)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00019b4a0, 0xa2d520, 0xc0001a4600)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36c
not implemented

goroutine 34 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack(0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x9f
runtime/debug.PrintStack()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:16 +0x25
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.DefaultRecover(0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cd1d0, 0x8fedc0, 0xc000390390, 0xc0002c2788, 0xc000390050)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/recovery.go:16 +0xaa
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.(*OperationContext).Recover(0xc0004a0f00, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cd1d0, 0x8fedc0, 0xc000390390, 0xc0002c2790, 0x8)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/context_operation.go:110 +0x56
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext)._Order_id.func1(0xc000390050, 0xc000390380, 0xc0000c9288)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:684 +0x79
panic(0x8fedc0, 0xc000390390)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:969 +0x1b9
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph.(*orderResolver).ID(0xc0001862b0, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cd1d0, 0xc00027a3f0, 0xc00019efc0, 0xc0001cd1d0, 0xc00004b400)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/schema.resolvers.go:60 +0x68
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext)._Order_id.func2(0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cd1d0, 0x20, 0x945f00, 0xa2d501, 0xc00019efc0)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:699 +0x99
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/executor.processExtensions.func3(0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cd1d0, 0xc00019efc0, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cd1d0, 0xc00019eea0, 0x0)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/executor/extensions.go:62 +0x3a
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext)._Order_id(0xc000390050, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc930, 0xc00048fc80, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc00027a3f0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:697 +0x1f8
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext)._Order.func1(0x0, 0x0)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:2205 +0xc5
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.(*FieldSet).Dispatch(0xc0000783c0)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/fieldset.go:34 +0x1dd
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext)._Order(0xc000390050, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc930, 0xc0001cc8d0, 0x3, 0x3, 0xc00027a3f0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:2230 +0x406
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext).marshalNOrder2ᚖgithubᚗcomᚋyangwawa0323ᚋgoᚑordersᚑgraphqlᚑapiᚋgraphᚋmodelᚐOrder(0xc000390050, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc930, 0xc0001cc8d0, 0x3, 0x3, 0xc00027a3f0, 0xc0001cc960, 0xc0000c9610)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:2692 +0x157
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext)._Mutation_createOrder(0xc000390050, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc900, 0xc00048fc00, 0xc0001cc8d0, 0x3, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:594 +0x366
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executionContext)._Mutation(0xc000390050, 0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc900, 0xc0004a9aa0, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc0001cc8a0, 0x30)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:2161 +0x67d
github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated.(*executableSchema).Exec.func2(0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc8a0, 0x10)
        /root/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated/generated.go:232 +0x7b
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/executor.(*Executor).DispatchOperation.func1.1.1(0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc8a0, 0xc000390060)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/executor/executor.go:105 +0x43
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/executor.processExtensions.func2(0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc8a0, 0xc000390060, 0xa19730)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/executor/extensions.go:59 +0x3a
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/executor.(*Executor).DispatchOperation.func1.1(0xa2d5e0, 0xc0001cc840, 0xc0001cc810)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/executor/executor.go:104 +0x12c
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/handler/transport.POST.Do(0xa2c1e0, 0xc0001e22a0, 0xc0004a0e00, 0xa2bda0, 0xc0001963f0)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/handler/transport/http_post.go:53 +0x3a8
github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/handler.(*Server).ServeHTTP(0xc0001da1c0, 0xa2c1e0, 0xc0001e22a0, 0xc0004a0e00)
        /root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.13.0/graphql/handler/server.go:115 +0x21b
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xcd53e0, 0xa2c1e0, 0xc0001e22a0, 0xc0004a0d00)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2417 +0x1ad
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0001e2000, 0xa2c1e0, 0xc0001e22a0, 0xc0004a0d00)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00019b4a0, 0xa2d520, 0xc0001a4600)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36c
```

- The following is my code.

```golang
// project root directory server.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/handler"
    "github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/playground"

    // _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph"
    "github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/generated"
    "github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api/graph/model"
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

const defaultPort = "8080"
const dbName = "test_db4"

var db *gorm.DB

func initDB() *gorm.DB {
    var err error
    dataSourceName := "root:secret@tcp(localhost:3306)/?parseTime=True"
    //db, err = gorm.Open("mysql", dataSourceName)
    db, err = gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dataSourceName), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    // db.LogMode(true)
    db.Debug()
    // Create the database. This is a one-time step.
    // Comment out if running multiple times - You may see an error otherwise
    db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s", dbName))
    db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("USE %s", dbName))
    // Migration to create tables for Order and Item schema
    db.AutoMigrate(&model.Order{}, &model.Item{})
    return db
}

func main() {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = defaultPort
    }

    initDB()

    srv := handler.NewDefaultServer(generated.NewExecutableSchema(generated.Config{
        Resolvers: &graph.Resolver{
            DB: db,
        }}))

    http.Handle("/", playground.Handler("GraphQL playground", "/query"))
    http.Handle("/query", srv)

    log.Printf("connect to http://localhost:%s/ for GraphQL playground", port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil))
}
```

- In case to prevent run `gqlgen generate` command again that **replace the models** I defined. I create a new go file

```golang
// graph/item_order.go

package model

import "gorm.io/gorm"

// Item struct
type Item struct {
    gorm.Model
    ProductCode string `json:"productCode"`
    ProductName string `json:"productName"`
    Quantity    int    `json:"quantity"`
    OrderID     uint   `json:"-"`
}

type Order struct {
    gorm.Model
    CustomerName string  `json:"customerName"`
    OrderAmount  float64 `json:"orderAmount"`
    Items        []*Item `gorm:"foreignKey:OrderID" json:"items"`
}
```

- The graph/resolver.go

```golang
package graph

// This file will not be regenerated automatically.
//
// It serves as dependency injection for your app, add any dependencies you require here.

import "gorm.io/gorm"

// Resolver struct
type Resolver struct {
    DB *gorm.DB
}
```

- The following is the schema.graphqls, you can use it generate the most code when running `gqlgen generate`.

```
type Order {
    id: Int!
    customerName: String!
    orderAmount: Float!
    items: [Item!]!
}

type Item {
    id: Int!
    productCode: String!
    productName: String!
    quantity: Int!
}

input OrderInput {
    customerName: String!
    orderAmount: Float!
    items: [ItemInput!]!
}

input ItemInput {
    productCode: String!
    productName: String!
    quantity: Int!
}

type Mutation {
    createOrder(input: OrderInput!): Order!
    updateOrder(orderId: Int!, input: OrderInput!): Order!
    deleteOrder(orderId: Int!): Boolean!
}

type Query {
    orders: [Order!]!
}
```

- there is the data I post from web browser

```
mutation createOrder ($input: OrderInput!) {
  createOrder(input: $input) {
    id
    customerName
    items {
      id
      productCode
      productName
      quantity
    }
  }
}
##########################################

mutation updateOrder ($orderId: Int!, $input: OrderInput!) {
  updateOrder(orderId: $orderId, input: $input) {
    id
    customerName
    items {
      id
      productCode
      productName
      quantity
    }
  }
}

query orders {
  orders {
    id  
    customerName
    items {
      productName
      quantity
    }
  }
}
```

query variable is:

```
{
  "orderId":4,
  "input": {
    "customerName": "Ken",
    "orderAmount": 9.99,
    "items": [
      {
      "productCode": "2323",
      "productName": "IPhone X",
      "quantity": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is about the `gqlgen`, it is not reaching the `gorm` part

Answer (score 2):

you must [implement your own resolver](https://gqlgen.com/getting-started/#implement-the-resolvers).

There are actually not lots of error messages, it is called `Stack Traces`.
There is only one error from the error message: `not implemented`

Comment: The solution of the author is better.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved, I am upgrade the gorm.io/gorm v.1.20.8 library

The following is my project go.mod file content.

```golang
module github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api

go 1.15

require (
        github.com/99designs/gqlgen v0.13.0
        github.com/agnivade/levenshtein v1.1.0 // indirect
        github.com/dgryski/trifles v0.0.0-20200830180326-aaf60a07f6a3 // indirect
        github.com/hashicorp/golang-lru v0.5.4 // indirect
        github.com/kr/text v0.2.0 // indirect
        github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure v1.4.0 // indirect
        github.com/stretchr/testify v1.6.1 // indirect
        github.com/vektah/gqlparser/v2 v2.1.0
        gopkg.in/check.v1 v1.0.0-20201130134442-10cb98267c6c // indirect
        gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.4.0 // indirect
        gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.0-20200615113413-eeeca48fe776 // indirect
        gorm.io/driver/mysql v1.0.3
        gorm.io/gorm v1.20.8
)
```

After upgrade the library, I run the command

```sh
shell$ gqlgen generate
```

Everything is fine.

This is my github.com source code. You can download and try if you are interested.

[go-orders-graphql-api](https://github.com/yangwawa0323/go-orders-graphql-api)